# How to run code loop if (a==b) and dont loop if a != b without "else"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this is how should work:

```
if(a == b)
    // loop code
else
    // run code one time no loop
```

but I want

```
if(a == b)
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)  // if a is equal b begin loop
some_function();             // if a is not equal b run code one time
```

**`Solved!!!`**

Comment: I do like the answer given by Torsten. But I must add this side note: you should use braces, putting `for` just like that without braces could be extremely error prone and buggy!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set loop limit.

```
int limit = a == b ? 1 : 10;
for (i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
{
   ...
}
```

If a == b, loop run one time. If a != b, loop run as many as you need (10 in your case).

Comment: awesome idea!! thanks :) this is what im looking for thanks again. and thanks to all who answered!! good luck to all

Answer (score 4):

Use a `do {} while` loop as it executes at least once:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
} while (a == b && i++ < 9);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve his question this just loops if a == b, doesn't change the limit as required.

Comment: Off-by-one error, `int i = 0; do { ... } while (i++ < 10);` isn't the same as `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { ... }`

Comment: @DaveMackintosh, it does solve the question. It executes exactly once if `a != b` and executes 10 times if `a == b`.

Answer (score 2):

Write your code in a method, call it in the loop as many times and after if, call it once.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Run the code one time first and if your condition is met run your loop (and adjust your loop expressions if required). Use a function if possible to not duplicate code.

```
run_code_one_time;

if (a == b) {
    your_loop;
}

// no else
```

Comment: -1 He's right to not want to use an else because it duplicates code. Your solution doesn't solve that.

Comment: Exactly, the call to the function is still duplicated. The request is to transform "if a equal b then BLAH ten times, otherwise BLAH once" into "do BLAH ten times if a equals b or once otherwise". It doesn't matter whether BLAH is one line or a hundred, the request is that it not be duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

```
  int limit = (a==b)? 10 :1;
      for (i=0;i<limit;i++) {
           //your code
      }
```

`limit` will be set to 10 if `a==b` else 0 otherwise

other way around

```
  int limit = (a==b)? 0 :9;
    for (i=limit;i<10;i++) {
         // your code
      }
```

`limit` will be set to 0 if `a==b` else 9 otherwise

Comment: Hurrah! No off-by-one error, and no assumption that `a` and `b` don't change in the loop. This does assume that `i` doesn't change in the loop body, but that's usually pretty safe.

Comment: @SteveJessop try for the second option

Comment: All I was thinking about was the crazy situation that if the code in "loop code" from the question modifies `i` downward, then it causes extra loops. So if the same code is used in the `a!=b` case (because you've commoned it up as requested), then it will cause extra loops in the `a!=b` case too. But thinking about it more, the questioner implies that the current code is the same code in both cases, and the loop variable `i` isn't even in scope in the current `a!=b` case, so it can't possibly modify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;

while (a == b)
{

    // code for when a is equal to b
    i++;
    if(i == 10)
        a = b+1;
}

// code for when a is not equal to b executed once
```